# Calculate slope over a gridded latitude/longitude coordinate area with corresponding depths in r

Tags: r, grid, coordinates, r-sp

I have built a gridded area in the Gulf of Alaska with a resolution of 0.02 decimal degrees (~1nm);

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

# Set interval for grid cells. 
my.interval=0.02 #If 1 is 1 degree, which is 60nm, than 0.1 is every 6nm, and 0.05 is every 
3nm, so 0.0167 is every 1nm

# Select range of coordinates for grid boundaries (UTM to maintain constant grid cell area regardless of geographic location).
lonmin = -140.5083
lonmax = -131.2889
latmin = 53.83333
latmax = 59.91667

LON = seq(lonmin, lonmax, by=my.interval)
LAT = seq(latmin, latmax, by=my.interval)

# Compile series of points for grid:
mygrd = expand.grid(
  Longitude = seq(lonmin, lonmax, by=my.interval),
  Latitude = seq(latmin, latmax, by=my.interval)) %>% 
  #mutate(z=1:n()) %>% 
  data.frame
```

I exported that grid as a .csv file and brought it into ArcGIS where I used a few bathymetry rasters to extract the bottom depth at the midpoint of each cell. I then exported that from GIS back into R as a .csv file data frame. So now it has another column called "Depth" on it. 
For now, I'll just add a column with random "depth" numbers in it:

```
mygrd$Depth<-NA
mygrd$Depth<-runif(nrow(mygrd), min=100, max=1000)
```

I would like to calculate the slope at the midpoint of each cell (between points).

I've been trying to do this with the slope() function in SDMTools package, which requires you to have a SpatialGridDataFrame in the sp package.

I can't get this to work; I am also not sure if this is the easiest way to do that? 
I have a data frame with 3 columns: Longitude, Latitude, and Depth. I'd like to calculate slope. If anyone knows any better way to do this, let me know! Any help is much appreciated!

Here is some of the code I've been trying to use:

```
library(SDMTools)
proj <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
coords <- mygrd[,1:2]
t2 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=coords, data=mgrd proj4string=proj)

t2<-SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points=t2[c("Longitude","Latitude")], data=t1[,c(1,2)])

t3 <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grid=NULL, data=t2, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

class(t3)
slope.test<-slope(t3, latlon=TRUE)
```